# I want to Coordinate civiCRM mailing list and SimpleNews Mailing list

Tags: groups, drupal-rules, newsletter

I send mailings two ways: via civiCRM newsletters and via SimpleNews newsletters. The problem is that I then have two different email lists, one in civiCRM and one in Drupal for SimpleNews. If users want to stop receiving emails, they have to unsubscribe twice. I would like people to be able to unsubscribe from either list, and be removed from both. So there are two parts to this: (1) on unsubscribe from SimpleNews, remove from civiCRM mailing list, and (2) on unsubscribe from civiCRM mailing list, remove from SimpleNews mailing list.

For (1), I was trying to create this rule: When an email is unsubscribed from SimpleNews (Action), then the email is also removed from civicrm group (Event). But I receive an error message: Data selector site:current-user:roles: for parameter contact is invalid. What should the data selector be? The only one that comes up as an option is "site:current-user:roles"

For (2), I have no idea how to do this. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Final Note: What I am trying to do may not be possible without using some third party such as MailChimp to coordinate email lists.

Comment: want to explain why the simplenews sign up needs to be retained rather than run it all via civi?

Comment: SimpleNews creates a content page at the same time as the newsletter, which is a function we want.

Comment: civimail offers a 'public' page version of the mailing. not the same thing but not sure if you knew that or not. also there is an extension around somewhere that lets you put a views token in a mailing, so you can - create your newsletter stuff in drupal - grab a views link - put token in civimail

Comment: i realise i am not trying to answer your question, just offer workarounds ;-)

Comment: maybe change the topic title to 'how do i use rules to unsub a contact from a civi group when they unsub from simplenews and v. v." ?

Comment: no, I am all for a work around, so thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of workarounds that may help you.

Civimail offers a 'public' page version of the mailing. not the same thing but not sure if you knew that or not. When you set up a Mailing you have the option of setting its visibility to public, and then there are Drupal permissions to determine what roles can access this.

Also there is an extension developed by Fuzion [here](https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/civicrm_views_token) that lets you put a Views token in a mailing, so you can

- create your newsletter stuff in drupal
- create a views display for this content
- put token in civimail